Broken pipe error with Ports between Elixir and C
I am attempting to write a program in Elixir that connects to a C program via Port and erl_interface. I got the C code up and running and managed to send data through the port as well as decode and encode, like the tutorials. However, I wish to send quite large data, namely the contents of images or files, through the port. The port exits with {:EXIT, #Port<x.x>, :epipe} which is the POSIX code for broken pipe when I try these large files. Is there some upper limit on the size of the data sent through the port, or is there some other reason for why the pipe breaks?
Relevant Elixir code:
port = Port.open({:spawn, "path/to/executable"}, [:binary, :exit_status, packet: 2])
Port.command(port, :erlang.term_to_binary(File.read!("path/to/file")))

(I have tried both packet: N and line: N options in Port.open/2, (with packet: 2 as in the examples provided below, I get {:EXIT, #Port<x.x>, :einval}))
C file:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "erl_comm.h"
#include "ei.h"

int main() {
    byte buf[100];
    ei_x_buff res_buf;
    
    ei_init();
    ei_x_new(res_buf);

    int read_bytes = read_cmd(buf);
}

Even with nothing in the while-loop I get the broken pipe error. This is the least amount of code that still produces the error.
erl_comm.h file:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

int read_exact(byte *buf, int len) {
  int i, got = 0;

  do {
    if ((i = read(0, buf + got, len - got)) <= 0) {
      return (i);
    }
    got += i;
  } while (got < len);

  return (len);
}

int write_exact(byte *buf, int len) {
  int i, wrote = 0;

  do {
    if ((i = write(1, buf + wrote, len - wrote)) <= 0)
      return (i);
    wrote += i;
  } while (wrote < len);

  return (len);
}

int read_cmd(byte *buf) {
  int len;

  if (read_exact(buf, 2) != 2)
    return (-1);
  len = (buf[0] << 8) | buf[1];
  return read_exact(buf, len);
}

int write_cmd(byte *buf, int len) {
  byte li;

  li = (len >> 8) & 0xff;
  write_exact(&li, 1);

  li = len & 0xff;
  write_exact(&li, 1);

  return write_exact(buf, len);
}

I build the C-file via
cc -fPIC \
-L/path/to/erl_interface/lib \
-lei -lpthread \
-I/path/to/erl_interface/include \
-o priv/port src/port.c

The file I have tested with have about 190000 bytes. After some debugging in erl_comm.h file with the read_cmd, it seems that read returns 0 immediately, and returns an :einval error when the packet: 2 option is provided to Port.open/2. read returns -1 immediately when line: N is provided. I am still at a loss on how to read these large files, any ideas on how to proceed?
Relevant docs:

erl_interface user guide
erl_interface introduction
erl_interface docs


You're missing a lot of relevant code...

And you should always save the return value of read() in a variable so you know how many bytes were read. I bet not doing so has something to do with the problem.

"The erl_comm file is taken directly from the tutorials." which tutorial?

Thanks for the replies, I have updated the question with more info regarding the problem.

The first thing that stands out is that you're reading upto 2^16 - 1 = 65535 bytes into a buffer that is only 100 bytes long.
